# converting object to json doesnt show empty List<object> unity

Tags: c#, arrays, json, list, unity-game-engine

```
private void Start()
    {
        a data = new a
        {
            name = "karan",
            l = new List<object>()
        };

        Debug.Log(JsonUtility.ToJson(data));
    }
```

output = {"name":"karan"}

expected output = {"name":"karan", "l":[]}

Comment: `JsonUtility` doesn't understand the type `List<object>` I guess. What is the list supposed to contain?

Comment: [{"message": hello, "sent":true}, {"message": hello how are you, "sources": "www.google.com", "sent":true}]

Comment: Then create a type for the above JSON

Answer (score 2):

`JsonUtility` uses the same serializer as the Inspector → see [Script Serialization](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html) and in particular [Serialization Rules](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html#SerializationRules)

⇒ `object` is not a serializable type. Even further The Unity serializer always serializes only the properties of the type that is stored in the list and `object` as the mother of all types and itself doesn't really have any meaningful properties to be serialized

As a simple rule regarding `JsonUtility`: If it doesn't show up in the Inspector it also will not show up in the resulting JSON and it will be ignored also when deserializing a JSON.

---

Instead you have to use a third-party library like e.g. `Newtonsoft Json.NET` (available as a [Package via Unity's PackageManager](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.nuget.newtonsoft-json@3.2/manual/index.html))

⇒ Then you would do e.g.

```
var objs = new List<object>
{
    "hello",
    "world!",
    42,
    new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 },
    new Dictionary<object, object>{
        {"Wow", 12},
        {"Easy now", false},
        {"Don't", "overdo it"},
    },
    true
};

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objs);
Debug.Log(json);
```

Results in

```
["hello","world!",42,[1,2,3],{"Wow":12,"Easy now":false,"Don't":"overdo it"},true]
```

or using

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objs, Formatting.Indented);
Debug.Log(json);
```

results in

```
[
  "hello",
  "world!",
  42,
  [
    1,
    2,
    3
  ],
  {
    "Wow": 12,
    "Easy now": false,
    "Don't": "overdo it"
  },
  true
]
```